# C++: Inheriting two base classes with same name, different namespace

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, constructor, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible to inherit two base classes that have the same name, if the are in different namespaces?

By the way, I'm not planning at this time on doing this, but I was curious:

```
class SuperShape : Physics::Shape, Graphics::Shape
{
    // constructor
    SuperShape( int x, int y, float color) : ???( x, y ), ???( color );
}
```

Comment: btw, you forgot to mention 'public' 'protected' or 'private' in the inheritance.

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: It's not necessary to indicate `public`, `protected` or `private`. In this case, it defaults to `private` since it is a `class`. For a `struct`, it defaults to `public`. Personally, I always explicitly state the access modifier, but the OP's code is valid C++ with respect to indicating base classes.

Comment: Re: "Is it possible to inherit two base classes that have the same name, if the are in different namespaces?"  The answer is YES, because *they do have different names*

Comment: @JohnDibling yes, that was explained in @GregHewgill's answer below.

Comment: In fact by all of the answers, but Greg's is worded most clearly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, why not? Nothing prevents you from doing so. Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

namespace NS1 {

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (const std::string &) {}
};

}

namespace NS2 {

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass (int) {}
};

}

class MyClass :
    public NS1::MyClass,
    public NS2::MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass () :
        NS1::MyClass (std::string ("Hello")),
        NS2::MyClass (1986)
    {}
};

int main ()
{
    MyClass clazz;
    std::cout << typeid (NS1::MyClass).name () << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid (NS2::MyClass).name () << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid (clazz).name () << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: almost all were good answers, but this one was the most thorough. thanks everybody!

Comment: How to perform `using contructor` syntax in this case?

Answer (score 9):

Well, simply :

```
SuperShape( int x, int y, float color)
    : Physics::Shape( x, y ), Graphics::Shape( color )
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Classes in different namespaces actually *do* have different names (as far as C++ is concerned), even though the last part of the name (`Shape` in your example) might be the same. The name resolution is performed on the *fully qualified* name, including all namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The constructor's mem-initializers will have to use qualified names.

```
SuperShape::SuperShape( int x, int y, float color )
    : Physics::Shape( x, y ), Graphics::Shape( color )
{ /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Physics::Shape & Graphics::Shape respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned that this is the only reason namespaces exist.  :)

Comment: This is not the _only_ reason namespaces exist.